# How to prove a function is bounded above?

Tags: calculus

Suppose $x > 0, 0 < t < 2$, prove that there exists a constant $c$ such that $$f(x) = x^t\ln\left(\dfrac{2}{x+1}\right) < c \quad \forall x.$$

When plotting the function $f$, the claim seems to be correct. But how to prove that mathematically?

Comment: $f$ is continuous, $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} = -\infty$.

Comment: A more detailed answer would be more helpful.

Comment: More details to @mathcounterexamples.net comment?  Extreme Value Theorem.  That should be all you need.

Comment: Oh, I can't help myself.  Show $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 0$.  Find an $a > 0$ so that $f(x) < 1$ for of $x \le a$.  Show $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = -\infty$.  Find a $b> a$ so that $f(x) < 0$ for all $x > b$.  Use extreme value theorem as set $m = \max f(x); x\in [a,b]$.  Let $c > \max(m,1)$. Done. ... meh, I probably gave too much away with this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that the limit as $x \rightarrow 0$ and limit as $x\rightarrow 1$ are equal to zero.

Show that $f$ is continuous on $x\in (0,1)$.

Conclude that $f$ is bounded on this interval by applying the extreme value theorem.

Finally, show that $f$ is decreasing on $(1,\infty)$.

Not a super detailed answer, but just trying to provide a general framework.